# iPhone: delegate of ModalViewController

Tags: iphone, delegates, modalviewcontroller

I have an issue by setting the delegate property for a ViewController which is presented modally. The code below is a modified copy of the example code for [Presenting a View Controller Modally](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ModalViewControllers/ModalViewControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH111-SW14).

```
            AddContactPersonTableViewController *addController = [[AddContactPersonTableViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"AddContactPersonTableViewController" bundle:nil];
            addController.delegate = self;

            UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:addController];
            [self presentModalViewController:navigationController animated:YES];

            [navigationController release];
            [addController release];
```

For `addController.delegate = self;` there is the error: "Request for member 'delegate' in something not a structure or union"

I don't know how to solve this. Maybe you can solve it ;)

Answer (score 0):

That does your AddContactPersonTableViewController.h look like. Did you add delegate protocol to this class? Do you need to set delegate? You probably dont even need to do it if you dont  need the previous viewcontroller to do some action when the new viewcontroller is dismissed or something like that..

Comment: I think, I need this property. After dismissing the ModalViewController the entered data should be stored in an array (instance attribute of previous viewcontroller).

Comment: Yeah if so you should use delegate.

Answer (score 0):

AddContactPersonTableViewController must have a property declared called delegate in your .h file like:

id delegate;

The delegate should also have a valid setter:
@property (nonatomic, retain) id delegate;

Comment: ohh .. I forgot to declare a property called delegate.

Comment: Well, the delegate's property are normally defined as (nonatomic, assign), not (nonatomic, retain). Delegates should not be retained.